# Foreign Key between federated tables in SQL Azure

Tags: sql, azure, create-table, federated

I have a problem..

I need to define foreign keys between federated tables, and I cant do it.. I have two tables...

```
CREATE TABLE Tarifa(
[cp_id] [int] NOT NULL,
[id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[nombre] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
[comision] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
[markUp] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id,cp_id)
) FEDERATED ON (cp_id=cp_id)


CREATE TABLE Periodo(
[cp_id] [int] NOT NULL,
[id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[tarId] [int] NOT NULL,
[precio] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id,cp_id)
) FEDERATED ON (cp_id=cp_id)
```

I want to reference the field tarId in Periodo to Tarifa. is It possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can reference federated table with some restrictions.

From the [Federation Guideline and Limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh597469.aspx):

> All foreign key constraints on federated tables need to include the
>   federation column on both the referrer and the referenced tables at
>   the same ordinal in the foreign key. Reference tables cannot have
>   foreign key relationships with federated tables. Federated tables can
>   have foreign key relationships with reference tables without
>   restrictions.

In your case you have to include the Federated Column on both the tables.